# convert an hashMap.toString back to hashmap

Tags: java

I have a log line from my logs like:

```
{Contact={attributes={type=Contact}, Id=003, Email=xxx@xxx.com,, Account={attributes={type=Account}, Name=NBC, LLC}}, fromAccount=true}
```

This was logged using HashMap.toString()

I need to convert it back to hashMap.

I tried objectMapper etc and looked around on google, I could not find a solution.

Please advise how to do.

Comment: You need to start by writing a `fromString()` (or equivalent) method for the class types you're storing in your map.

Comment: There's no guarantee that it's possible. `toString()` is meant to make something human readable, but often that won't include all the information about the object.

Comment: Im gonna have to agree with azurefrog. I don't thing java supports parsing from String to HashMap. You're gonna have to split the string and reorganize it into a map

Comment: It isn't possible. Consider a HashMap that contained strings like `"foo, bar=quux"` and `"outer, inner={fred=barney}"`. There is no way to parse it back, unless the objects it contains are very carefully designed for it. Maybe not even then. Why not just use JSON?

Comment: If your HashMap stores consistent keys, your could parse each value out using regex with probably good reliability, although values that may contain commas could be problematic

Answer (score 0):

You could use Snake Yaml which looks like this and creates a Map by default, but the problem you have is non standard field syntax like

```
, Name=NBC, LCC
```

The first `,` is a separator, the second is part of the field.  The `,,` is also a bit odd.  Is there a `,` at the end of a value?